# petite-vue mount and unmount events with nested v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, petite-vue

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting multiple/extra `mount` and `unmount` events in petite-vue.  I've seen similar questions with regard to Vue proper (and components), and I think they are in the same realm, but still a bit confused.

It seems that when I do get all the multiple `mount` events, there is only one event triggered where the element being mounted is has `el.isConnected=true` so I could maybe use that as a trigger as to whether or not to run the attached event handler, but I'm worried about performance as the number of events build and build while modifying the model state.

Is the a different way I should be writing these so I don't get multiple events ?

**Scenarios :**

1. Click Edit, then Cancel: Why two unmounts for the v-for="item in model.beneficiaries" ?
2. Click Edit, then Save: All OK. Click Accept: Why `isConnected = false` mount on 'Edit Screen' ?
3. Repeat cycles of Edit, Cancel or Edit Save, then Accept and read notes about acceptClicks.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/terryaney/52nbzr6e/)

```html
<script type="module">
    import { createApp, reactive } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'

    const state = reactive({
        setMode: function (benefit) {
            var beneficiaries = benefit == undefined ? [] : [ "Spouse", "Son" ];
            this.model.beneficiaries = beneficiaries;
            this.model.currentBenefit = benefit;
            this.model.showConfirm = false;
        },
        startEdit: function (benefit) {
            console.log("Edit Clicked");
            this.setMode(benefit);
        },
        cancelEdit: function () {
            console.log("Cancel Clicked");
            this.setMode();
        },
        saveBenefit: function () {
            console.log("Save Clicked");
            this.model.showConfirm = true;
        },
        acceptBenefit: function () {
            console.log("Accept Clicked");
            this.model.acceptClicks++;
            this.setMode();
        },
        model: {
            acceptClicks: 0,
            currentBenefit: undefined,
            showConfirm: false,
            beneficiaries: []
        }
    });

    createApp(state).mount('#app')
</script>

<div id="app" v-scope>
    <div>State:</div>
    <div>currentBenefit: {{model.currentBenefit == undefined ? 'undefined' : 'set'}}</div>
    <div>showConfirm: {{model.showConfirm}}</div>
    <div>beneficiaries: {{model.beneficiaries.length}}</div>
    <div>acceptClicks: {{model.acceptClicks}}</div>
    <div v-if="model.acceptClicks > 0">
        <div>After each Accept</div>
        <ul>
            <li>When clicking Edit, {{model.acceptClicks}} isConnected=false mounts for 'Has Beneficiaries', 'Spouse' and 'Son'</li>
            <li>When clicking Edit, then Cancel, {{2 + model.acceptClicks * 2}} unmounts for 'Spouse' and 'Son'; {{1 + model.acceptClicks}} unmounts for 'Has Beneficiaries'</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div v-if="model.currentBenefit != undefined">
        <h3>Editing {{model.currentBenefit?.name}}</h3>
        <div v-if="!model.showConfirm">
            <div @vue:mounted="console.log('Mount: ' + $el.innerHTML + ', isConnected: ' + $el.isConnected)" @vue:unmounted="console.log('Unmount: ' + $el.innerHTML)">Edit Screen</div>
            <div v-if="model.beneficiaries.length > 0">
                <div @vue:mounted="console.log('Mount: ' + $el.innerHTML + ', isConnected: ' + $el.isConnected)" @vue:unmounted="console.log('Unmount: ' + $el.innerHTML)">Has Beneficiaries</div>
                <div v-for="item in model.beneficiaries">
                    <div @vue:mounted="console.log('Mount: ' + $el.innerHTML + ', isConnected: ' + $el.isConnected)" @vue:unmounted="console.log('Unmount: ' + $el.innerHTML)">{{item}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="button" @click.prevent="cancelEdit">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" @click.prevent="saveBenefit">Save Benefit</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="model.showConfirm">
            <button type="button" @click.prevent="acceptBenefit">Accept Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="model.currentBenefit == undefined">
        <h3>No Benefit</h3>
        <button type="button" @click.prevent="startEdit($event, { name: 'Health Benefit' })">Edit Benefit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time on this, I observed that the condition `v-if="model.beneficiaries.length > 0"` is not making any sense as you already added a condition at top level div `v-if="model.currentBenefit !== undefined"`.

If `model.currentBenefit` value will not be undefined then obviously `model.beneficiaries` will always contains a length as per the assignment you did in `setMode` function.

Hence, removing that inner `v-if` will resolve the issue you are facing.

Reason / Root cause behind the issue **:**

As per the [`documentation`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#unmounted), When `unmounted` hook has been called, all directives of the component instance have been unbound, all event listeners have been removed, which results in loading the directive again and logs the console multiple times.

Here is the [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/96eabnmf/) link for the demo. In this demo you can see that I added same condition two times in a DOM and it is calling `@vue:unmounted` two times.

Comment: In the sample, I always puts two beneficiaries in the benefit, but in my application, this is data driven.  A valid benefit can have no beneficiaries.  I didn't put the 'else' condition of length == 0, but there is one.  Looking at your fiddle, I'm not sure two identical conditions are a valid test (and your increment disappears so you can't repeat on/off scenarios, although I changed it and it seemed to continue to work as you described).  On mine, if you click edit, save, accept, and that is probably far enough to to investigate first, why do I get a 'mount' again on 'Edit Screen'?

Comment: @Terry Just for a demo purpose, I added two identical conditions in the jsfiddle link. The main reason behind that behaviour is that when unmounted hook has been called, all directives of the component instance have been unbound